# Creating dataframe column by matching with second dataframe and pulling data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2 dataframes:

df1:

```
 ID         STORE_ID    total_visits_area
 10000085   306A        3
 10000100   060A        2
 10000100   059A        1
```

df2:

```
ID      STORE_ID_1  STORE_ID_2  ACCOUNT_NAME    
05451394    060A       029B         wade O'Donnell
10000100    060A       059A         Jane Smith
```

I want to add a 2 column to `df2` where I match on `BH_ID` and `STORE_ID` from `df1` and pull in the visits number where if `STORE_ID` matches in `df2` in `STORE_ID_1` then the visits would be pulled into `STORE_ID_1_VISITS`

output df:

```
ID      STORE_ID_1  STORE_ID_2  ACCOUNT_NAME    STORE_ID_1_VISITS  STORE_ID_2_VISITS
05451394    060A       059A     wade O'Donnell  2                  0
10000100    060A       059A     Jane Smith      2                  1
```

I tried using np.where but got a ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The data of your example doesn't seem to make sense. Please double check

Comment: @mozway updated to give you an example

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the merge function. Something like:

> df_out=pd.merge(df2, df1.rename(columns='total_visits_area':'STORE_ID_1_VISITS'},left_on=['ID', 'STORE_ID_1'],right_on=['ID', 'STORE_ID'])

Then again on the second column

> df_out=pd.merge(df2,df1.rename(columns='total_visits_area':'STORE_ID_2_VISITS'},    left_on=['ID', 'STORE_ID_2'],
> right_on=['ID', 'STORE_ID'])

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mapping Series:

```
smap = df1.set_index('STORE_ID')['total_visits_area']
df2['STORE_ID_1_VISITS'] = df2['STORE_ID_1'].map(smap).fillna(0).astype(int)
df2['STORE_ID_2_VISITS'] = df2['STORE_ID_2'].map(smap).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
>>> df2
         ID STORE_ID_1 STORE_ID_2    ACCOUNT_NAME  STORE_ID_1_VISITS  STORE_ID_2_VISITS
0   5451394       060A       029B  wade O'Donnell                  2                  0
1  10000100       060A       059A      Jane Smith                  2                  1
```